# A strange scheduling for $K_{24}$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

This question came from a question asked earlier today linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403945/grouping-kids-in-groups-of-4)

The question implicitly asked how to make a schedule with his/her class of 24 students such that:
1)  Everyday will consist of the 24 students split into 6 groups of 4 students.
2)  Over the course of several days, every pair of students will have been in a group with one another.

This seems like it might be a Steiner system, but i'm not exactly sure. [Steiner system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) $S(2,4,24)$.
I've found that a necessary condition for this system existing is the existence of $S(1,3,23)$.  Now here's where I'm not sure if I'm following the definition of Steiner system exactly.  This system, $S(1,3,23)$ would be a $K_3$ decomposition of $K_{23}$, would it not?  **Perhaps this is not exactly a Steiner system, this is part of my question.  Help me to clear this up**

How many days would be required to schedule this?
Well, we need to partition the edges of $K_{24}$ which has $\binom{24}{2}$ edges.  Each $K_4$ has 6 edges.  So on a single day we would have 36 edges while we need a total of 276 edges.  However, $\frac{276}{36}$ is not an integer, so this actually tells us that **we can't do this if we require no edges to be repeated.**  So, some pairs of students will be in the same group with each-other more than once.

**The Question**:  What is the minimum number of days required to schedule this?  Will $\lceil\frac{276}{36}\rceil = 8$ days be sufficient?  What exactly am I dealing with here?  Some sort of design?  A Steiner system?  What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [Social Golfer Problem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/). Best you can do without repetition is 7 days. But you can likely find an 8th day that fills in all the gaps.

day 1:  ABKU    IJSE    QRCM    DGFX    HLNO    PTVW
day 2:  ACLV    IKTF    QSDN    EHGR    BMOP    JUWX
day 3:  ADMW    ILUG    QTEO    FBHS    CJNP    KRVX
day 4:  AENX    IMVH    QUFP    GCBT    DJKO    LRSW
day 5:  AFOR    INWB    QVGJ    HDCU    EKLP    MSTX
day 6:  AGPS    IOXC    QWHK    BEDV    FJLM    NRTU
day 7:  AHJT    IPRD    QXBL    CFEW    GKMN    OSUV